# Finding correct row in data extracted from PDF to text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am trying to get data out of pdf files, convert them to CSV, then organize into one table.

A sample pdf can be found here

https://www.ttb.gov/statistics/2011/201101wine.pdf

It's data on US wine production. So far, I have been able to get the PDF files and convert them into CSV.

Here is the CSV file that has been converted from PDF:

https://github.com/jjangmes/wine_data/blob/master/csv_data/201101wine.txt

However, when I try to find data by row, it's not working.

```
require 'csv'

csv_in = CSV.read('201001wine.txt', :row_sep => :auto, :col_sep => ";")

csv_in.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

When I put line[0], I get the entire data being printed. So it looks like the entire data is just shoved into row[0].

```
line will extract all the data. 
line[0] will extract all the data with space in between lines.
line[1] gives the error "/bin/bash: shell_session_update: command not found"
```

How can I correctly divide up the data so I can parse them by row?

This is a really messy data with no heading or ID, so I think the best approach is to get the data in csv, and find the data I want by looking up the right row number.

Though not all data have the same number of rows, most do. So I thought that'd be the best way for now.

Thanks!

Edit 1:

Here is the code that I have to scrape and get the data.

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'docsplit'
require 'byebug'
require 'csv'

def pdf_to_text(pdf_filename)
    extracted_text = Docsplit.extract_text([pdf_filename], ocr: false, col_sep: ";", output: 'csv_data')

    extracted_text
end

def save_by_year(starting, ending)
  agent = Mechanize.new{|a| a.ssl_version, a.verify_mode = 'TLSv1', OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}
  agent.get('https://www.ttb.gov')
  (starting..ending).each do |year|
    year_page = agent.get("/statistics/#{year}winestats.shtml")
      (1..12).each do |month|
        month_trail = '%02d' % month
        link = year_page.links_with(:href => "20#{year}/20#{year}#{month_trail}wine.pdf").first
        page = agent.click(link)

        File.open(page.filename.gsub(" /","_"), 'w+b') do |file|
          file << page.body.strip
        end

        pdf_to_text("20#{year}#{month_trail}wine.pdf")
      end
  end
end
```

After converting, I am trying to access the data through accessing the text file then row in each.

Comment: That doesn't seem anything like a CSV file and I doubt trying to treat it as such will yield much results. You might be better off trying to extract explicitly from the PDF.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for a gem that extracts pdf? I just read about pdf-reader and looks good.

Comment: Given it's a government document they usually have two versions available: one is pdf, and the other is excel.CSV. if you have that then life becomes much easier. I would recommend against pdf extraction because, well, as you know it's a nightmore. the trick is to find the same file in excel format

Comment: I found the data from https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/wine-production-and-operations-report but can't seem to find data type other than pdf. It states data is available in HTML, but I'm not sure how to approach this.